# abi.decode() and unused variables

Tags: solidity, abi, solc

I am decoding bytes as the following:

```
      // Decode Solidity tightly packed arguments
      (uint8 _, uint128 stakeId, address behalf) = abi.decode(userData, (uint8, uint128, address));  // solhint-disable-line
```

I get a compiler warning:

```
Variable '_' is declared but never used.
```

What would be the right way to suppress this warning beautifully? I know how to do this for function arguments, but not sure how what is a good practice with `abi.decode`.

The obvious way does not work:

```
/Users/moo/code/dawn-erc20/contracts/Staking.sol:255:23: ParserError: Expected ',' but got identifier
      (uint8, uint128 stakeId, address behalf) = abi.decode(userData, (uint8, uint128, address));  // solhint-disable-line
```

Comment: Why not `(, uint128 stakeId, address behalf) = abi.decode(userData, (uint8, uint128, address));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get rid of it in the function-call as well, i.e.:

```
(uint128 stakeId, address behalf) = abi.decode(userData, (uint128, address));
```

But I suppose that would just beat your purpose to begin with.

So the quickest workaround which comes to mind is to just add a dummy reference:

```
(uint8 _, uint128 stakeId, address behalf) = abi.decode(userData, (uint8, uint128, address));
_; // a dummy reference to an unused local variable
```

Comment: this "obvious" way does not work - see the updated question.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa: See updated answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
(, uint128 stakeId, address behalf) = abi.decode(userData, (uint8, uint128, address));
```

Try this, it should work ;)